# What's the smartest way of making my couchapp searchable?

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, couchdb, elasticsearch

I know, there's couchdb-lucene, but I'm hosted on the amazing IrisCouch and I can't really install plugins. Any other options left? What sort of setup would be the simplest and most transparent and would allow me to continue working with the magnificence that CouchDB is without worrying about the search layer?

Consideration: I have about 8 million documents, so creating a specific view that emits each word in each of my documents would not be very efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that [CouchDB river](http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/2010/08/01/couchb-integration.html) plugin for elasticsearch will suite your needs. It doesn't need any configuration on CouchDB side -- all that you need to do is to perform very simple setup on elasticsearch node.

Comment: But you still need to install the plugin? I'm using a sandboxed hosted couchdb instance where I can't install plugins

Comment: You don't install a plugin to CouchDB. This plugin is installed on the elasticsearch side and acts like a ordinary CouchDB client (subscribing to the `_changes` feed).

Comment: ! Ah really? interesting! I'll check it out!